# Grails file upload json response

Tags: json, grails, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file in grails and then process a json response that is returned from the upload, but I'm not having much success. My view looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addData(e) {
  alert('adding data');
  }
</script>

<g:form name="upload-form" url="[controller: 'dataset', action:'handleUpload']"
enctype="multipart/form-data" target="hidden-upload-frame">
  File: <input type="file" name="myFile" />
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</g:form>
<iframe id="hidden-upload-frame" name="hidden-upload-frame" style="display: none"   onload="addData"></iframe>
```

And in my controller I have

```
def handleUpload() {
  def file = request.getFile('myFile')
  def result
  // do some fileprocessing to create the result
  render results as JSON
```

}

But when I submit the form, the browser just prompts me to download the JSON response. I had also tried using a formRemote, but the request.getFile does not seem to be valid for formRemote.

What do I need to do to get the `addData` method to get called with the json response?

Answer (score 0):

When writing to an iframe, it seems like for some browsers it needs to be written as text or html, not as json.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to return JSON in your handleUpload action your return  (last line) must be:

```
 render result as JSON
```

also you need the following import:

```
 import grails.converters.JSON
```

Comment: Ernesto, I changed that and it does properly render the json to the iframe, but I still can't seem to make the callback to the addData javascript method work

Comment: Also on firefox it still tries to download the json file, not render it to the frame (it renders to the frame on chrome though)